# Dynamic :last-child in SASS

Tags: css, css-selectors, sass, pseudo-class

I've been messing around with SASS for a while and have made some nice functions that makes use of @if @else if etc. However I have the following two pieces of code on a Mixin:

```
&:last-child { float: right; margin-right: 0; } 
&:only-child { float: left; margin-right: 0; }
```

This obviously applies both of these pieces of code to every element I include this particular Mixin on. Is there a way of dynamically checking whether an element is a :last-child / :only:child with an @if statement or any other methods?

Something like:

```
@if :last-child == True { float: right; margin-right:0; }
```

Hopefully I've explained that well enough.

Thanks

Comment: The mere presence of `:last-child` alone will help you test if an element is the last child.

Comment: @BoltClock Yep but it repeats the code for every element I include the Mixin on. If it's the only-child I'd like it do that function, if it's the last-child I'd like it to do a different function, not check for both.

Answer (score 11):

Sass doesn't know anything about your document.  It can't check if the element is the first-child or only-child.  Sass can only be used to generate valid CSS.

If you're looking for the last-child that is not an only-child, this is your selector:

```
&:last-child:not(:only-child) {
    // styles
}
```

http://tinker.io/1717b

If you're wanting to disable output of one or the other (because you already know that only one of them will be applicable in this instance), then you'll need an extra argument passed to your mixin:

```
@mixin foo($children: true) {
  @if $children or $children == last-child {
    &:last-child {
      // styles
    }
  }
  @if $children or $children == only-child {
    &:only-child {
      // styles
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah thats sucks, guess I was trying to do to much programming with SASS? My only option it would seem would be to add my :last-child rules to a Mixin that people have to include on the last-child element themselves?

Comment: Yes, that is what I would recommend.  Multiple smaller mixins that can be used (or not used) together is better than one large mixin that has a long string of arguments.

Comment: The only other solution would to be use consistent class names but I a feature of my system is so users can have arbitrary/semantic class names. Is there any way of achieving a dynamic solution for this using another language and/or the use of a database?

Comment: I don't understand why this is a problem or why you want to get databases involved in this (what benefit do you think this will give you?).  Modularized code is the best way to give your users the flexibility they're looking for, particularly if they're the kind of user that wants to integrate it seamlessly with their own coding style.

Comment: Well for my grid system to work as desired it is essential the :last-child floats right (due to sub pixel rendering problems). I can either give the user the choice of painfully having to remember to attach a custom mixin to float the last-child themselves (no hardship for most people but still annoying) or I add the mixin to every element by default and deal with repeated code.

Comment: If your code is done modularly ("columns styles" mixin, "last-child styles" mixin, "last-of-type styles" mixin), then all you need to do is create additional mixins that invoke those to make it easy to get code that *just works*, while letting power users call them individually as they see fit.